# Chrome processes even though I have uninstaled Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I installed Chrome several weeks ago and didn't like it. So I uninstalled.  But now I see that I have Chrome processes running and have started getting messages that Chrome is causing a high CPU load.  How do I stop these processes from loading?

Comment: Does this happen even after a reboot ?

Comment: Yes! These processes are all: otwtjlgwv.exe

Comment: It's google so who knows what they are up to. It's probably a gov entity by now. Check your registry to see if there are any traces to Chrome in there and (if you know what you are doing) delete them. Or use a registry cleaner software that you trust.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a malware. I would suggest using [AdwCleaner](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/adwcleaner/) or [Malwarebytes Anti-Rootkit](https://www.malwarebytes.com/antirootkit/) to remove the malware.